# Running Command Lines in a makefile

Tags: shell, makefile

I'm trying to figure out how to run a program with inputs from the command line using a makefile.

For example, let's say I have a program foo that takes in two integers and adds them and returns the result. In the make file when I type in make test for example it'll go into my makefile and it'd look like this

```
test:
     ./foo 1 1
     ./foo 2 2
```

and so on, but when I'm trying to do it it doesn't run. Is there something I am missing?

Comment: When you run the `make` command, are you in the directory where `foo` is? What if you use an absolute path to the program? Oh, and *what* error(s) do you get?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Actually no, right now I have a main folder called project and the executable is in project/program and my testing makefile is in project/testing. I assumed that I'd simply have to do ./project/program/foo 1 1 to make it work. The error I am getting is that the ./project/program/foo command was not found

Comment: And you are sure that `$PWD/project/program/foo` exists (and has the x-bit set)? BTW, the error complains about `project/program/foo`, but you have in your makefile. Maybe you are looking at the wrong place for the error. In any case, I would put a `ls -l` as the first command below the *test* target in your makefile. Also, in case `foo` happens to be a shell script, I would call it with `-x`. Maybe this foo **does** run, but then tries to execute a different *foo* in another directory, which causes the error.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the absolute path of your Makefile with:

```
mkfile_path := $(abspath $(lastword $(MAKEFILE_LIST)))
```

Then, you can build your executable path with:

```
exe_path := $(mkfile_path)/../program
```

Finally, invoque `foo` with its path:

```
$(exe_path)/foo 1 1
```

Comment: What is abspath, lastword, and MAKEFILE_LIST?

Comment: These are internal functions and variables of GNU Make (see documentation: [abspath](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/File-Name-Functions.html#File-Name-Functions), [lastword](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Text-Functions.html#Text-Functions), [MAKEFILE_LIST](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Special-Variables.html#index-makefiles_002c-and-MAKEFILE_005fLIST-variable))